# R ERROR in reading 18 GBs data

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a text file that contains about 2.86 billion records that I have to import in R data frame. My server has 64GB RAM and 48 cores. When I read file via `read.table` command, about 25 GB RAM was being used. But before it finished, An error occured

```
 "runs out of space"
```

I think, It is due to some data frame limit. Can I have a dataframe of 2.86 billion rows (any limit problem) ?If yes then how I can import my data or to analyze such data. Input data file size is about 18 GB. My data file contains single column( an integer value). I have find a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r) that have given some options but that data in much that my case.

Comment: try the fread function in data.table package.

Comment: I like the `readr` package and read files chunk wise. Maybe this helps if you don't need the complete data in memory.

Comment: You may find [Row limit for data.table in R using fread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17596249/3817004) useful.