# r read.table too many items

Tags: r, read.table

I have a file with the size of 53 Gb and here's its head:

```
1   10  2873
1   100 22246
1   1000    28474
1   10000   35663
1   10001   35755
1   10002   35944
1   10003   36387
1   10004   36453
1   10005   36758
1   10006   37240
```

I'm running R 3.3.2 on a CentOS7 64-bit server with RAM of 128 Gb. I've read 4098 similar files into R. However, I can't read the largest one into R.

```
df <- read.table(f, header=FALSE, col.names=c('a', 'b', 'dist'), sep='\t', quote='', comment.char='')
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : har='')
  too many items
```

It returns error saying "too many items". Then I followed this [tip](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~rpeng/docs/R-large-tables.html):

```
df5rows <- read.table(f, nrows=5, header=FALSE, col.names=c('a', 'b', 'dist'), sep='\t', quote='', comment.char='')
classes <- sapply(df5rows, class)
df <- read.table(f, nrows=3231959401, colClass=classes, header=FALSE, col.names=c('a', 'b', 'dist'), sep='\t', quote='', comment.char='')
```

It still says "too many items", and "NAs are introduced". I also tried without `colClasses`, same result:

```
df <- read.table(f, nrows=3231959401, header=FALSE, col.names=c('a', 'b', 'dist'), sep='\t', quote='', comment.char='')
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : har='')
  too many items
In addition: Warning message:
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

The memory used never went over 90 Gb (when without any `nrows` or `colClasses`, with those args it never went over 60 Gb). I don't understand why R can't read the file.

I've also checked that there's no line with 4 or more columns.

Comment: Since that's a pretty big file, have you tried using `data.table::fread`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I bumped into `fread` while googling this problem, never used it before. I read its features (https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Convenience-features-of-fread) but I still don't know if it is compatible with `igraph`. It's an edgelist file and I need to do `g <- graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = FALSE)` next.

Comment: Yep, that shouldn't be a problem. If you prefere you can even tell `fread` to return a `data.frame` instead of `data.table` (though I wouldn't necessarily recommend that with data of such size)

Comment: @docendodiscimus could you add this as an answer? It seems to me the best solution.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra thanks for your help! I'm using `fread` and I think I know the problem now. As `fread` returned, `nrow larger than current 2^31 limit`, the file has 3231959401 lines. I tried `fread(f, nrows=3231959401)` and it says `'nrows' must be a single non-NA number of type numeric or integer`. The only related thread I can find is  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596249/row-limit-for-data-table-in-r-using-fread and to be honest, I don't quite follow. Do you have some suggestion to bypass the limit? Or I can try splitting the file too.

Comment: You could split the file as @DamienCormann suggested indeed. However, remember that reading a 53 GB file as one object will make it hard to do anything usefull with it with 128 GB RAM. I would suggest you decide if you need the full data or not.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to cut the file using a light editor such as (sed or VI)?
Then you just have to merge the two dataset.
On a very similar machine  with big file, I experienced the same problem. 
Its was a junk line, with regard of the size of the file those kind of errors occurs.

Comment: This would be an option I agree, but simply using `fread` already solves this issue without any additional steps needed. In addition a bit of a nitpick, sed is not a text editor but a command line text processing tool.

Comment: The OP updated his question, you suggestion seems to be much more relevant now :). +1!